# How to get battery percentage from the browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, browser, batterylevel

How to get the user's battery percentage on a web application using JavaScript.

Since it's a web application, it'll run on a browser. The percentage will be displayed on the webpage.

Comment: javascript (unless it's nodejs) and css won't help - so, keep trying with java and/or python, they have access to OS details that you need

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Battery status API. It only works on some browsers like chrome.

```
navigator.getBattery()
  .then(function(battery) {
    console.log(battery.level);
});
```

[You can find more information here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/battery-status/)

> **The link provided is a candidate recommendation and is not a finalized api.**

Comment: Note that this API never made its way to the specs (the link you provided was just a CR) and after FF dropped its support for web scripts because of privacy concerns, I doubt it will ever make it, and would rather see it removed from Blink too in a near future. However, for OP's case, it should be noted that this API is still supported in FF too for chrome:// scripts (extensions), and will probably stay there for ever.

Comment: Thank you. I included that the link is a CR.